# Insert child element after another in Pixi.js

Tags: javascript, 2d, appendchild, pixi.js

### Scenario

I making a 2d visualization of two round rectangles as following:

```
const app = new PIXI.Application({ backgroundColor: 0xffffff} );
const roundBox = new PIXI.Graphics();
roundBox.lineStyle(4, 0x99CCFF, 1);
roundBox.beginFill(0xffffff);
roundBox.drawRoundedRect(0, 0, 200, 100, 10);
roundBox.endFill();

const roundBox2 = new PIXI.Graphics();
roundBox2.lineStyle(4, 0x99CCFF, 1);
roundBox2.beginFill(0xffffff);
roundBox2.drawRoundedRect(0, 0, 200, 100, 10);
roundBox2.endFill();
app.stage.addChild(roundBox, roundBox2);
```

I want to append horizontally the second rectangle without calculating the horizontal position of the second child.

### Question

Is there a way to insert horizontally a graphic element in pixi.js?

Answer (score 0):

You can rotate the second rectangle 90 degrees, like this:

```
// Center the point to rotate this rectangle at its center
roundBox2.pivot = new PIXI.Point(100, 50);

// Math.PI / 2 is equal to 90 degrees in radians.
roundBox2.rotation = Math.PI / 2;
```